# Can't write NSDictionary parameters into custom Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, object, nsdictionary

I was stuck on writing NSDictionary into Object process, I am sure that problem is simple as I imagine but would be great to get assistant. Here is my code:

my custom object:

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *cId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;
....

-(instancetype) initWithParameters:(NSDictionary*) parameters;

@end


#import "User.h"

@implementation User

-(instancetype) initWithParameters:(NSDictionary*) parameters
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setParameters:parameters];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setParameters:(NSDictionary*) parameters{
    _cId = parameters[@"cId"];
    _firstName = parameters[@"first_name"];
    _lastName = parameters[@"last_name"];
    ....
}
```

and writing process:

```
id userObjects = [resultData objectForKey:@"data"];
NSMutableArray* mUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary* userParameters in userObjects) {
    User *user = [[User alloc] initWithParameters:userParameters];
    [mUsers addObject:user];
}
```

userObjects - NSArray got from JSON object from server data.

The problem is : nothing happening and user object still empty after initialization, then I have tried - setValuesForKeysWithDictionary after I called variables same as keys in dictionary and nothing changed.

[image]

after adding in mUsers:
[image]

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Have you debugged initWithParameters? Whether it is going under this condition if (self) {

Comment: `user` is just a local variable, what is in `mUsers`? And I would avoid to declare methods starting with `set` because that could be treated as a property setter.

Comment: @Kiran yes, and debugger just moving step by step no warnings or logs, everything going well but vars still empty.

Comment: as vadian said.. user is local variable. You try to log mUsers.

Comment: @vadian function name in this case doesn't matter because I've tried doing this job right in init function. mUsers is just NSMutableArray you can see above

Comment: Once again, what does `mUsers` contain after the repeat loop?

Comment: @vadian mUsers contains user with no values, I've added one more picture above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you think those objects are uninitialized because you are seeing `0 key/value pairs` next to each `User` object.

Your code looks good and I think things will change once you implement `[NSObject description]` (or `[NSObject debugDescription]`) like this:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cId=%@, firstName=%@, lastName=%@",
        _cId, _firstName, _lastName];
}
```

Comment: you was right, I've used logs and there was all needed info, strange that I've relied on debugger, my fault :) Thank you!